# How to select an element and call a jquery plugin on it

Tags: jquery, flash, colors, background, jquery-animate

I have an FAQ section of my website in which I'd like to flash the background property of the div of the answer of the question clicked using this particular function

```
// Extend jquery with flashing for elements
$.fn.flash = function(duration, iterations) {
    duration = duration || 1000; // Default to 1 second
    iterations = iterations || 1; // Default to 1 iteration
    var iterationDuration = duration / iterations;

    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        this.fadeOut(iterationDuration).fadeIn(iterationDuration);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to use the calling statement

```
$("#someElementId").flash(1000, 4);
```

to accomplish this.  My HTML looks like this

---

```
<p><ul class="disc">
<li><a href="#a1">Question</a></li>
```

---

```
<div class="row"><a name="a1">
<strong>Question</strong>

<p>Answer</p>

<a href="#top"><em>Back to top</em></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, put some classes on your elements and tie it all together:

```
<p><ul class="disc">
<li><a href="#a1" class='question' data-num='1'>Question</a></li>
<div class="row"><a name="a1">
<strong>Question</strong>

<p class='answer-1'>Answer</p>

<a href="#top"><em>Back to top</em></a>

$(function(){
  $(".question").on('click', function(){
     var num = $(this).data('num');
     $(".answer-"+num).flash(1000, 4);
  });
});
```

on document load when the user clicks on a question, i check that questions number which is stored in the data-num attribute. from that i can derive the answer's class which i flash.

Comment: that would work but there's no such function as 'flash.'  There should also be a ');' after the first '}.'

Comment: fixed syntax. you yourself defined `flash` as a query plugin. i am calling it.

Comment: yea, i think i saw that flash thing somewhere and thought it might work without actually testing it.  The proper way to do it is include jQueryUI and use the "pulsate" effect. `$("#a"+num).effect( 'pulsate', 'slow' );`